# CSS attributes is not working proper to my ASP page

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I'm new to ASP so please bear with me.
I have 5 ASP pages, I have attached a stylesheet to all of them, but 2 page is working fine and remaining 3 is not, its showing css problem css attribute is not working I think its doctype problem but i have change that one also but still error remains its not taking class attribute.
Please guide me how to resolve this problem.

`doctype` which i used is below. Is it proper or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: That doctype looks fine. I doubt that the doctype is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to copy the part   `<html> to </head>`   from the page which runs css properly
 and change this part with   `<html> to </head>`  part in the page where css not running properly.**

Answer (score -1):

hi whether u are writing an 
1.external style sheet or 
2.internal style sheet.

```
  if u r calling external style sheet be sure with the path..or 

  if it is internal style sheet,PLACE the style tag in the header and try..or please show the doc which is not working..
```

Comment: This is not a text being sent through a telephone. Please do us the favor and spell it all out properly.

Comment: thanks i m using externel stylesheet other some classes is working and some is not i checked a whole thing i review a css also but the same problem is coming i hope so you understood what is problem

Comment: @ MAYUR not a big issue..if only some classes are not working try placing those classes in the header of the html doc with style tag..because document level style sheets will have more priority than external style sheets..

Comment: @mayur may be more than two classes could have been with the same name..try to look at those things properly.

Comment: @Joel Etherton hey buddy is it clearly looking for u now ..if not please tell me i will try to change .

Comment: Thanks bharath i tried that it working fine but i cant use internal styling bcoz there are some incude file and i cant change that

Comment: @bharath - No. My meaning was to stop using "ur", "u", etc. Not everyone on this site is a native english speaker and may not understand that these are shorthand for "your", "you're", "you".